# Are there any possible changes in optimization while using different syntax for switch statement?

Tags: c, performance, syntax, switch-statement

Which is better performance in following two code snippets? and why?

**Snippet 1:**

```
 switch(a)
 {
      case 1 ... 5:
                   printf("%d\n",a);
                   break;
     case 6 ... 10:
                  printf("%d\n",a);
                  break;
    default:
            printf("%d\n",a);
 }
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
switch(a)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
          printf("%d\n",a);
          break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
           printf("%d\n",a);
           break;
   default:
           printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Comment: The above is a GCC extension. Quite obvious why the second is better

Comment: The former won't even compile in standard C. Which non-standard compiler are you using?

Comment: Why don;t you check the generated assembly code, for starters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the snippets are *same*, they are **not** different. You're just using a different *syntax* for writing the code, that's all.

As already mentioned in comments, the first approach makes use of **[gcc extension for case-range](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges).** It allows you to write *shorter* code at the cost of *portability*, so choose wisely.

Any (*half-decent*) compiler, while generating the assembly, will generate the same code, so performance-wise there should be no difference.

Answer (score 2):

If in doubt profile it.

But note that the first snippet is **not** standard C (the range `switch` is a notable gcc compiler extension), and so is therefore not portable.

`switch ((a - 1) / 5)` would be an obvious alternative if you don't like duplicating case labels. But this could wind up being slower; again, profile it. Presumably you are aware that the `printf` is the performance bottleneck by a country mile?

Comment: Your alternative may be easily writable, but it is slower in terms of performance, as the OP is asking about. Maybe you should state it.